# how to create new tag or select from current tags using Django forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I have 3 tables, Products, Articles, and tags.
products and articles both have a "tags" field which has ManyToMany relation with the "tags" table

I want to be able to reference multiple tags or create new tags while adding a product or an article (in one field)(using Django forms)

for example, "test1" and "test2" are already in the tags table, I want the field to be like this:
1.I type "te" in the tags field
2.A drop down with "test1" and "test2" is opened which I can choose each one of them to be added in the field
3.I type "test3" (which isn't already in the tags table)and hit enter and "test3" is added to the field
products and articles both have a "tags" field which has ManyToMany relation with the "tags" table
(just like tags in a post in StackOverflow)

I think Django built-in forms can handle this but I'm overwhelmed by the documentation and lost in the configuration of my Django forms.
what kind of fields and widgets should I use for this purpose?
Excuse me if the question is vague I'm new to Django and I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Is this for the Django Admin or is it for a frontend?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by front-end... it's not for the Django Admin, it's for the admin panel that I've written for the website admin so they could create/edit articles or products

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light?

Comment: yeah. but it was too complicated to use just one time. I figured it out. I did it with a combination of an Ajax call and its endpoint for searching in the current tags plus some JS to get the JSON data and put it in the field and finally in the Views file I implemented some logic for this field of the form so the data would be saved in the correct normalized format after the form submission.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. I did it with a combination of an Ajax call and its endpoint for searching in the current tags plus some JS to get the JSON data and put it in the field and finally in the Views file I implemented some logic for this field of the form so the data would be saved in the correct normalized format after the form submission.